How to merge tarin and test dataset after splitting but each row back to its original position or index
from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
# Load diabetes dataset  
diabetes = fetch_openml("diabetes", version=1, as_frame=True)
diabetes_df = diabetes.data
diabetes_df['target'] = diabetes.target  # Adding target column

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
# Split the data
train, test = train_test_split(diabetes_df, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

I want to combine both Train and Test dataset but same as original data index.
Note:But after make some miss I split the dataset to trian and test dataset and imputed train and test dataset separately
